# Matlab2tikz breaks major tick weight

Tags: pgfplots, fontsize, matlab, matlab2tikz, ticks

`matlab2tikz` breaks my tick weights on both x-and-y axis.  The figure in MATLAB looks like following.

[image: Original MATLAB Figure]

After running it through `matlab2tikz` with all possible known options of `ExtraAxisOptions`, I manage to get only the following figure (where the minor tick marks are gone completely and the major tick marks become faint).

[image: matlb2tikz conversion result]

I don't care too much about the minor tickmark weights, but how do I retain as much of the weight of the major tick marks from my original matlab figure?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What does "all possible known options of `ExtraAxisOptions` mean exactly?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

If `matlab2tikz` doesn't pick up modifications you have done to your plots in Matlab I think the best thing to do is to let the author know about this, by making a bug report at https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/issues

That said, I don't know what you've done in Matlab, or with `matlab2tikz`, but you can certainly add some `ExtraAxisOptions` to make a plot similar to your first screenshot.

```
% make some data kind of similar to what you have
x = 1000:1000:8000;
y = x.^2/640000;

plot(x,y,'.-','markeredgecolor','r','markerfacecolor','r','linewidth',3,'markersize',10)

% specify tick positions and xlim
set(gca,'xtick',0:2000:8000,'ytick',0:10:100,'xlim',[1000,8000])

matlab2tikz('testticks.tex',...
    'width','7cm','height','3cm',...
    'ExtraAxisOptions',['minor x tick num=8,minor y tick num=1,'...
               'xtick style={thick,black},ytick style={thick,black},'...
               'axis line style=thick'])
```

So the options passed to `pgfplots` are

- `minor x tick num=8,minor y tick num=1` - should be self explanatory I guess. Sets the number of minor ticks between major ticks.
- `xtick style={thick,black},ytick style={thick,black}` - sets the drawing style for the ticks, making them thicker and black.
- `axis line style=thick` - Having ticks that are thicker than the axis box doesn't look too good, so make this `thick` as well.

The result of running the above code is shown below. The `markersize` could be reduced a bit I see.

[image]